# Can't figure out why my android app's reset button wont work

Tags: android

I have been working on this app today and I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with the code.

I can run the app just fine on the emulator and my Motorola Bravo (2.2) but when I finish a round and press the "reset" button, it suddenly gives me an error that the program doesn't work anymore. Is there any way to fix this?

here is the logcat error (the whole red section):

```
12-20 23:01:27.636: E/StrictMode(585): null
12-20 23:01:27.636: E/StrictMode(585): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service     com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection     com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40ceb270 that was originally     bound here
12-20 23:01:27.636: E/StrictMode(585):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
12-20 23:01:27.636: E/StrictMode(585):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
12-20 23:01:27.636: E/StrictMode(585):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
12-20 23:01:27.636: E/StrictMode(585):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
12-20 23:01:27.636: E/StrictMode(585):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
12-20 23:01:27.636: E/StrictMode(585):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
12-20 23:01:27.636: E/StrictMode(585):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
12-20 23:01:27.636: E/StrictMode(585):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId  (AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
12-20 23:01:27.636: E/StrictMode(585):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
12-20 23:01:27.636: E/StrictMode(585):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
12-20 23:01:27.636: E/StrictMode(585):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
12-20 23:01:27.636: E/StrictMode(585):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
12-20 23:01:27.636: E/StrictMode(585):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-20 23:01:27.636: E/StrictMode(585):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-20 23:01:27.636: E/StrictMode(585):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-20 23:01:27.636: E/StrictMode(585):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-20 23:01:27.636: E/StrictMode(585):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

here is my source file:

```
package com.example.rockpaperscissorlizardspock;
import java.util.Random;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class rockpaperscissorlizardspock extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private TextView resultText;
    private Button play, reset;
    private ImageButton scissors, paper, rock, lizard, spock;
    private int paperimg, paper_pressedimg, scissorsimg, scissors_pressedimg,     rockimg, rock_pressedimg, lizardimg, lizard_pressedimg, spockimg, spock_pressedimg;
        private ImageView compSciss, compPaper, compRock, compLiz, compSpock;
    Random rand = new Random();
    int compChoice = 0;
    String pChoice ="";
    String cChoice = "";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Initialize();
    }

    /** initialize all of the components*/
     private void Initialize()
    {
        play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        resultText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultText);
        lizard = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
        spock = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
        scissors = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
        paper = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        rock = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        compSciss = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.computerScissors);
        compPaper = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.computerPaper);
        compRock = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.computerRock);
        spockimg = R.raw.spock;
        spock_pressedimg = R.raw.spock_pressed;
        lizardimg = R.raw.lizard;
        lizard_pressedimg = R.raw.lizard_pressed;
        paperimg = R.raw.paper;
        paper_pressedimg = R.raw.paper_pressed;
        scissorsimg = R.raw.scissors;
        scissors_pressedimg = R.raw.scissors_pressed;
        rockimg = R.raw.rock1;
        rock_pressedimg = R.raw.rock1_pressed;

        /**set the button Listeners*/
        play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View arg0){
                play();
            }
        });

        reset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
             public void onClick(View arg0){
                paper.setImageResource(paperimg);

                 rock.setImageResource(rockimg);
                scissors.setImageResource(scissorsimg);
                lizard.setImageResource(lizardimg);
                spock.setImageResource(spockimg);
                compPaper.setImageResource(paperimg);
                compRock.setImageResource(rockimg);
                compSciss.setImageResource(scissorsimg);
                compLiz.setImageResource(lizardimg);
                compSpock.setImageResource    (spockimg);               
                pChoice = "";
                cChoice = "";
                play.setEnabled(false);
                reset.setEnabled(true);
                scissors.setEnabled(true);
                paper.setEnabled(true);
                rock.setEnabled(true);
                lizard.setEnabled(true);
                spock.setEnabled(true);
                resultText.setText("");
            }
        });

        /*
         * Declaring what happens when specific choices are made.
         */

        scissors.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
             public void onClick(View arg0){    
                     scissors.setImageResource(scissors_pressedimg);
                    paper.setImageResource(paperimg);
                    rock.setImageResource(rockimg);
                    spock.setImageResource(spockimg);
                    lizard.setImageResource(lizardimg);
                    pChoice = "S";
                    play.setEnabled(true);
             }
         });

         paper.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View arg0){
                    paper.setImageResource(paper_pressedimg);
                    scissors.setImageResource(scissorsimg);
                    spock.setImageResource(spockimg);
                    rock.setImageResource(rockimg);
                    lizard.setImageResource(lizardimg);
                    pChoice = "P";
                    play.setEnabled(true);
            }
         });

        rock.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View arg0){
                rock.setImageResource(rock_pressedimg);
                scissors.setImageResource(scissorsimg);
                paper.setImageResource(paperimg);
                spock.setImageResource(spockimg);
                lizard.setImageResource(lizardimg);
                pChoice = "R";
                play.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });

        lizard.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
             public void onClick(View arg0){
                 lizard.setImageResource(lizard_pressedimg);
                 spock.setImageResource(spockimg);
                 rock.setImageResource(rockimg);
                 scissors.setImageResource(scissorsimg);
                 paper.setImageResource(paperimg);
                 pChoice = "L";
                 play.setEnabled(true);
            }
         });

        spock.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View arg0){
                spock.setImageResource(spock_pressedimg);
                lizard.setImageResource(lizardimg);
                rock.setImageResource(rockimg);
                scissors.setImageResource(scissorsimg);
                paper.setImageResource(paperimg);
                pChoice = "SP";
                play.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });

    }

    /**The method that chooses the computer's move and compares
     *  to the player's move.
     */
    public void play()
    {
        compChoice = rand.nextInt(5);

        if(compChoice == 0)
        {
            cChoice = "R";
            compRock.setImageResource(rock_pressedimg);
            }
        else if(compChoice == 1){
            cChoice = "P";
            compPaper.setImageResource(paper_pressedimg);
        }       
         else if(compChoice == 2)
        {
            cChoice = "S";
            compSciss.setImageResource(scissors_pressedimg);
            }
        else if(compChoice == 3)
           {
            cChoice = "L";
             compLiz.setImageResource(lizard_pressedimg);
            }
        else if(compChoice == 4)
       { 
       cChoice = "SP";
       compSpock.setImageResource(spock_pressedimg);
       }

    check();
}

/**
 * Compares the Computer's and the Player's moves.
 */
public void check()
{
    if(pChoice == "R") //Rock
    {
        if(cChoice == "R")
            resultText.setText("Draw");

        else if(cChoice == "P")
            resultText.setText("You Lose");

        else if(cChoice == "S")
            resultText.setText("You Win");

        else if(cChoice == "L")
            resultText.setText("You Win");

        else if(cChoice == "SP")
            resultText.setText("You Lose");
    }

    else if(pChoice == "P") //Paper
    {
        if(cChoice == "R")
            resultText.setText("You Win");

        else if(cChoice == "P")
            resultText.setText("Draw");

        else if(cChoice == "S")
            resultText.setText("You Lose");

        else if(cChoice == "SP")
            resultText.setText("You Win");

        else if(cChoice == "L")
            resultText.setText("You Lose");


    }

    else if(pChoice == "S") //Scissors
    {
        if(cChoice == "R")
            resultText.setText("You Lose");

        else if(cChoice == "P")
            resultText.setText("You Win");

        else if(cChoice == "S")
            resultText.setText("Draw");

        else if(cChoice == "L")
            resultText.setText("You Win");

        else if(cChoice == "SP")
            resultText.setText("You Lose");


    }

    else if(pChoice == "L") //Lizard
    {
      if(cChoice == "R")
        resultText.setText("You Lose");

      else if(cChoice == "L")
        resultText.setText("Draw");

      else if(cChoice == "SP")
        resultText.setText("You Win");

      else if(cChoice == "S")
        resultText.setText("You Lose");

      else if(cChoice == "P")
        resultText.setText("You Win");
    }

    else if(pChoice == "SP") //Spock
    {
        if(cChoice == "SP")
            resultText.setText("Draw");

        else if(cChoice == "L")
            resultText.setText("You Lose");

        else if(cChoice == "S")
            resultText.setText("You Win");

        else if(cChoice == "P")
            resultText.setText("You Lose");

        else if(cChoice == "R")
            resultText.setText("You Win");

    }

    gameOver();
}


/**
 * Runs at the end of each round. Disables all of the buttons
 * except for the reset button.
 */
public void gameOver()
{
    play.setEnabled(false);
    scissors.setEnabled(false);
    rock.setEnabled(false);
    paper.setEnabled(false);
    spock.setEnabled(false);
    lizard.setEnabled(false);
    reset.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a tricky error in this  `com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked...`

Sometimes this kind of errors happen and have nothing to do with your code.
I recommend you doing this but can not guarantee if it will work.

1. For the emulator, try creating a new AVD and test it there.
2. As for your device, uninstall the application and retry again. If it happens again please tell me if it happens at the first try or not.